# Oracle - Selecting only the maximum value from a column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, select

the structure of my DB is roughly this (simplified) :

Three tables: Order, step, material

The table "order" contains the columns `ID` and `material`

The table "step" contains the column `ID`, `order` and `stepnumber`

The table "material" contains the column `ID` and `description`

```
            Order                         
    --------------------------------    
     **ID** **Number**     **Material**    
       1         X1            11
       2         X2            12
       3         X3            13


              Step
   ---------------------------------------
   **ID**    **Order**  **Stepnumber***
     1          X1           X110
     2          X1           X120
     3          X1           X170
     4          X1           X180
     5          X2           X270
     6          X2           X280

                 Material
   ---------------------------------------
  **ID**      **Description***
    11             Mat1
    12             Mat2
    13             Mat3
```

The thing to notice is that the column `stepnumber`of the table is formed by the order number (ex. X1) and a number that identifies a step (10, 20, 70, 80, etc.), and as you can see there are multiple values of the `stepnumber` column that refers to the same order.

I'm using this query:

```
select order.number,step.stepnumber, material.id,material.description, 
from db.order inner join db.stepnumber
on order.number = step.order
inner join db.material
on material.id = order.material
where step.stepnumber not like '%10'
and step.stepnumber not like '%20'
group by order.number, step.stepnumber, material.id, material.description
```

As you can see from the query, I want to extract order and step data, and I'm excluding some step based on the `stepnumber` value.

Right now, the query output is:

```
order.number step.stepnumber material.id material.description 
-------------------------------------------------------------
  X1             X170             11           Mat1
  X1             X180             11           Mat1
  X2             X270             12           Mat2
  X2             X280             12           Mat2
```

I want to achieve that for every order only one row is extracted, taking the one in which the `stepnumber` value is higher. So the results should be:

```
order.number step.stepnumber material.id material.description 
-------------------------------------------------------------
  X1             X180             11           Mat1
  X2             X280             12           Mat2
```

I've tried putting the `MAX`function to `step.stepnumber` in the select with no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
CREATE TABLE "Order"(
   ID int,
   "Number" varchar(50),
   Material int
);


INSERT INTO  "Order" VALUES (1,'X1',11);
INSERT INTO  "Order" VALUES (2,'X2',12);
INSERT INTO  "Order" VALUES (3,'X3',13);

CREATE TABLE Step(
   ID int,
   "Order" varchar(50),
   Stepnumber varchar(50)
);


insert into Step values (1,'X1','X110');
insert into Step values (2,'X1','X120');
insert into Step values (3,'X1','X170');
insert into Step values (4,'X1','X180');
insert into Step values (5,'X2','X270');
insert into Step values (6,'X2','X280');

CREATE TABLE Material(
   ID int,
   Description varchar(50)
);               


INSERT INTO Material VALUES (11,'Mat1');
INSERT INTO Material VALUES (12,'Mat2');
INSERT INTO Material VALUES (13,'Mat3');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT "Number",STEPNUMBER,ID,DESCRIPTION 
FROM (
  select o."Number",
           s.stepnumber, 
           m.id,
           m.description,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY o."Number" ORDER BY s.stepnumber DESC) rn
    from db."Order" o
    inner join db.Step s on o."Number" = s."Order"
    inner join db.material m on m.id = o.material
    where 
        s.stepnumber not like '%10'
    and 
        s.stepnumber not like '%20'
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66182/21/0)**:

```
| Number | STEPNUMBER | ID | DESCRIPTION |
|--------|------------|----|-------------|
|     X1 |       X180 | 11 |        Mat1 |
|     X2 |       X280 | 12 |        Mat2 |
```

**NOTE**

We might try to avoid to use `Order`, `Number` be columns name or table name ... because they are keywords in Oracle.

Comment: I receive the error ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @Ponzaro Becasue there are too many keywords in your columns you can try my sqlfiddle.

Comment: I see that you SQLFiddle works without problems but for me it's not working :( Now it shows error ORA-00904 invalid identifier for all the identifiers in the main select

Comment: Try to add `db.` in  `from` calues your table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182685/discussion-between-ponzaro-and-d-shih).

Comment: @Ponzaro I return your mail again